# Electrolytic capacitor failure mode

Tags: capacitor, failure, vibration, component-failure

In a project we're working on, we had an electrolytic capacitor explode on us. It was a surface mount device, [UCM1H470MCL1GS](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/293/e_ucm-883824.pdf) from Nichicon:

[image: Electrolytic capacitor]

So far, we've seen our project run for many hundreds of hours without incident, so I'm fairly sure there is no fundamental error in the circuit causing these capacitors to be subject to over-voltage (they have a regulated 24v voltage across them).

However, our project does experience a lot of vibration and shock loading.

Question: Is it possible for vibration to cause a capacitor to fail short circuit, or in some other way that causes it to produce clouds of smoke?

The datasheet mentions the importance of careful handling, but doesn't seem to specify the failure modes in the case of mechanical abuse.

Comment: In my experience, in general, reverse-installed electrolytic capacitors readily explode, as will capacitors which exceed their maximum (forward or reverse) voltage.  I see them used commonly in industrial applications, under conformal coating, so perhaps a different model (with extra supports as Rohat explains) is warranted here.  Also consider the electrical anomalies at the time of failure.

Comment: It's common to find EL caps glued down to the PCB in audio equipment, to make sure they can't vibrate around.   Generally I see this done with RTV (silicon).  I do it with Hot Melt sometimes because I can't stand the smell of curing RTV.

Comment: Important question that you didn't address... DO THESE GET HOT???   I mean, while a "good" one is operating, can you put your finger on it and hold it there???     If not, then I know why your caps are exploding.....

Comment: Is this used on the output of a switching power supply? Ripple current can cause heating and eventually failure.

Comment: @KyleB I doubt it matters, but you could use neutral-cure RTV.  I used it a lot in a previous job for mounting optics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *our project does experience a lot of vibration and shock loading.*

The [data sheet for the Panasonic FN series](https://b2b-api.panasonic.eu/file_stream/pids/fileversion/9127) (for example) has this to say (look at #9): -

[image]

Note that I'm referring to the Panasonic data sheet because the picture in the question was originally a Panasonic FN capacitor: -

[image]

But anyway, the Panasonic list above isn't specific to Panasonic - it's a fairly standard thing for all suppliers. But, Panasonic, to their credit (and I do rate their electrolytic capacitors) are explicit about problems you may encounter.

So, you can assume that the list above pretty much applies to all electrolytic capacitors having a wet electrolyte.

> *Question: Is it possible for vibration to cause a capacitor to fail
> short circuit, or in some other way that causes it to produce clouds
> of smoke?*

Yes it is.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I am very, very sorry. I posted the wrong part number. However, since the capacitor package seems pretty similar, presumably the same considerations apply?

Comment: What part number is it?

Comment: I have corrected the question.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet the same considerations apply to the rather inferior (IMHO) Nichicon capacitor as per what I said in my answer: `So, you can assume that the list above pretty much applies to all electrolytic capacitors having a wet electrolyte.`

Comment: That is a good euphemism for exploding: "rapid deterioration of characteristics and functions of customer systems".

Answer (score 10):

As you might know, aluminium electrolytic capacitors are made from conductor foils separated by one or more dielectrics (e.g. paper).

[image]

Src: [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Construction-of-Electrolytic-Capacitor-1_fig1_241195108)

For a non-vibration-proof capacitor, excessive pressure or vibration may lead the separator to get mechanically damaged or move or another situation leading to a possible short between anode and cathode. Vibration-proof capacitors have extra supports inside to prevent any move of the foils and separators.

And a capacitor with shorted anode and cathode foils is happy to explode.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to blow a surface mount capacitor: In our case, the housing of the PCB actually hugs the capacitor fairly close, keeping it roughly in position, even if it becomes detached from the board.

Vibrations caused the capacitor legs to fatigue and fail, but the capacitor was kept in place, wobbling and rotating with the vibrations.

After a while, it rotated a full 180º, and for a moment touched the PCB reversed. This caused it to explode.

There are burn marks on the housing which match marks on the capacitor which shows it was reversed polarised when it exploded.

Since it had already run for many hours, I think it's safe to say that it probably hadn't been soldered the wrong way round, but instead had rotated after the legs fatigued.

Comment: Wow, thanks for letting us know. I don't think anyone would have ever guessed anything like that failure mode.

Comment: Good work here. Never come across that one before.